# Looking for a way to correctly strip a string

Tags: python

I'm using the Spotify API to get song data from a lot of songs. To this end, I need to input the song URI intro an API call. To obtain the song URI's, I'm using another API endpoint. It returns the URI in this form: `'spotify:track:5CQ30WqJwcep0pYcV4AMNc'` I only need the URI part,

So I used `'spotify:track:5CQ30WqJwcep0pYcV4AMNc'.strip("spotify:track)` to strip away the first part. Only this did not work as expected, as this call also removes the trailing "c".

I tried to built a regex to strip away the first part, but instructions were too complicated and D**K is now stuck in ceiling fan :'(. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `replace()`, not `strip()`.

Comment: Apart from `replace` you can also do `.split(":")[-1]`.

Comment: Of course.... Thanks guys.... Knew there was a simpler way than regex....

Answer (score 2):

`strip()` removes all the leading and trailing characters that are in the in the argument string, it doesn't match the string exactly.

You can use `replace()` to remove an exact string:

```
'spotify:track:5CQ30WqJwcep0pYcV4AMNc'.replace("spotify:track:", "")
```

or split it at `:` characters:

```
'spotify:track:5CQ30WqJwcep0pYcV4AMNc'.split(":")[-1]
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

Use simple regex replace:

```py
import re

txt = 'spotify:track:5CQ30WqJwcep0pYcV4AMNc'
pat_to_strip = ['^spotify\:track', 'MNc$']
pat = f'({")|(".join(pat_to_strip)})'
txt = re.sub(pat, '', txt)

# outputs:
>>> txt

:5CQ30WqJwcep0pYcV4A
```

Essentially the patterns starting with `^` will be stripped from the beginning, and the ones ending with `$` will be stripped from the end.

I stripped last 3 letters just as an example.